# Using `minted` environment inside a `tabu` table

Tags: tables, verbatim, minted, tabu

I am trying to use a piece of highlighted code using the `minted` package inside a `tabu` table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}       
    \begin{tabu*}{X[5,l]X[5,l]}
        \begin{minted}{matlab}
function out = op(x, y)
    out = x + y;
end
        \end{minted}
        & \\
    \end{tabu*}
\end{document}
```

With the above MWE I tried to place a `minted` environment inside a `tabu` cell analogously to what was done with the `Verbatim` environment explained within the `tabu` package documentation in section 1.3 "Inserting Verbatim material (fancyvrb)". However, by compiling the above MWE I get the following error message:

```
Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.15     \end{tabu*}
                    ^^J
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

If I try to compile the document in scroll mode (`-interaction=scrollmode` with XeLaTeX from MiKTeX), I just get a command prompt with `Enter file name:`.

How can the `minted` environment be used within a `tabu` table?

Comment: `minted` is very different from `Verbatim`, because it has to write its contents in a file, then call an external program and input the resulting file.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment. I know that `minted` uses these temporary files. What makes me curious is that if I just press my `Enter` key twice in `scrollmode` the output is generated as expected without an additional error.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the multiple passes `tabu` does on cell entries.

Comment: @egreg I don't know. I am not able to figure out where the problem is and I was also not able to find anything regarding the utilization of `minted` inside a `tabu` table on the web.

Comment: Usual caveat about `tabu`: the author has long promised a new version, stating it will have a number of incompatibilities with the current one. My advice is to contact the author.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Comment: @Jubobs: Looks interesting, however, I will wait until the package is published on CTAN for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @DigNative The package has just been released on CTAN `:)` However, you might have to wait a few days for all the CTAN mirrors to catch up before being able to install the package directly through your package manager.

Comment: @Jubobs: Ahh, fine. Then I will have a look on the package the next time I need to display MATLAB code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a hack than a real fix.  `minted` correctly creates the highlighted content, and the content is correctly brought in.  But at some point, `minted`'s `\minted@pygmentize` macro tries to `\input` a file that "doesn't exist."  I put "doesn't exist" in quotes because I've tried `minted` with all file deletion disabled, and still get the error--so it seems to be related to `tabu`'s multiple passes.  Anyway, the `Enter file name:` can be avoided by patching `tabu*`.  Basically, replace every `\input` with an `\InputIfFileExists`.  Insert the following in the preamble, after `tabu` is loaded, and you document will compile.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\originalinput\input
\newcommand{\newinput}[1]{\InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabu*}{\let\input\newinput}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am now able to compile my document without any errors.